# return unique values from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that contains cities, I want to return an array of all those cities, but it must be a unique list of the cities.

The array below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [eventname] => Wine Tasting
            [date] => 12/20/2013
            [time] => 17:00:00
            [location] => Anaheim Convention Center
            [description] => This is a test description
            [city] => Anaheim
            [state] => California
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [eventname] => Circus
            [date] => 12/22/2013
            [time] => 18:30:00
            [location] => LAX
            [description] => Description for LAX event
            [city] => Anaheim
            [state] => California
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [eventname] => Blues Fest
            [date] => 3/14/2014
            [time] => 17:00:00
            [location] => Austin Times Center
            [description] => Blues concert
            [city] => Austin
            [state] => Texas
        )

)
```

Should return:

```
array('Anaheim', 'Austin');
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: First you iterate through all entries in the array above and pick the cities into a temporary array, then you use phps `array_unique` function on that temporary array.

Comment: _“Any help is appreciated”_ – any _own efforts_ are too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `array_map` to get all the cities, then `array_unique` to remove duplicates.

```
$cities = array_unique(array_map(function($x) { return $x['city']; }, $array));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add them as a key forcing it to be unique and then flip it, or:

```
foreach($events as $details) {
    $cities[] = $details['city'];
}
$cities = array_unique($cities);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $val) {
  $cities[$val['city']] = '';
}
$cities = array_keys($cities);
```

Comment: I deleted my answer. Good luck :)